# what's the difference between webpack:// and webpack-internal://

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm writing a *webpack-react-typescript* kit, and I've found that the `source-map` can't direct to the source code.

It directs to the `webpack-internal://src/App.tsx file`, this file has some webpack injection code.

Another computer has both the `webpack://` and `webpack-internal` domain, and the source map, which in the `webpack://` domain can't direct to the current source code.

So what I want to know is:

1. What's the difference between `webpack` and `webpack-internal`?
2. Why does one computer have `webpack://` and the other one doesn't?

Answer (score 3):

There's an error in chrome displaying source maps, which is the reason why it is suffixed like that.

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/8a7597aa6eb2eef66a8f9db3a0c49bcb96022a94/lib/EvalSourceMapDevToolModuleTemplatePlugin.js#L88-L95

The chrome team seems to be neutral to solving this
https://twitter.com/ChromeDevTools/status/960972070711476224